# Open Modal in a specific date/time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been developing a web app, and I was wondering if there is a way to display a model at a specific date/time.

In the app, the user can book task or reminders, so when I read from the database the task a specific I want to schedule the display of the modal at the date/time specify by the user.

For instance, the user book a task for 2013-09-23 at 14:00 and I want to display a message in the modal.

I kwon we can set time interval with the JavaScript:

```
setInterval(function () { 
    showModal(); 
}, 10 * 1000);
```

But how to specify an hour like in the sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers, they help me come up with a solution:

```
function setNotification(notificationDate, notificationCallback){
     var currentDate = new Date();
     var date = new Date(notificationDate);
     var interval = date - currentDate; 

    if(interval > 0)
        window.setTimeout(function(){ notificationCallback(item)}, interval); //notificationCallback = showModal()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that `setInterval` call, `10 * 1000` means 10 times 1000 milliseconds, or in other words 10 seconds. If you want an hour, it's just a bigger number. `1000 * 60 * 60` is an hour.

However, `setInterval` is for running a function multiple times. Unless you wanted it to be called *every* hour, you are probably looking for `setTimeout` instead. `setTimeout` schedules a function to be run once after the time period expires.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

1. Make your **`setInterval()`** to run for a continues time.
2. Compare the date, by converting them to **`milliseconds`**. and a comparison condition.

---

```
setInterval(function () { 
 var date = new Date("2013-09-23 14:00");
 var schDateSecs = Date.parse(date);
 var currentDate = new Date();
 var schCurrentSecs = Date.parse(currentDate);
 if (schDateSecs == schCurrentSecs) {
    //execute
    showModal(); 
 }
}, 10 * 1000);
```